# Can we disallow to use || on optional types by lint?

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I want to disallow following code:

```
function(num: undefined|number) {
  return num || 10;
}
```

I want use `??` instead of `||`.

Comment: https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/prefer-nullish-coalescing/

Comment: Note that for num `0`, nullish coalescing will return `0` while the or operator will return `10`.

Comment: @JSONDerulo I believe that's exactly the reason to prefer `??` - to avoid defaulting when using a falsy value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the rule [@typescript-eslint/prefer-nullish-coalescing](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/prefer-nullish-coalescing/):

> This rule reports when you may consider replacing:
>
> - An `||` operator with `??`
> - An `||=` operator with `??=`

Also note that the rule documentation states:

> **CAUTION**
>
> This rule will not work as expected if `strictNullChecks` is not enabled.

To enable it add `"@typescript-eslint/prefer-nullish-coalescing": "error"` to the rules in the linter configuration.

Read the documentation page for additional configuration options for the rule.